# Mobile menu is working in Jfiddle but not on local host

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was creating a responsive mobile menu using a toggleClass function to open the menu. I have it working in Jfiddle and even bellow but for every time I click the nav icon in the live preview in brackets it does nothing. I have even tested it in a new blank brackets project and still not able to click it open.

Code included in jfiddle as well as bellow

Any help is greatly appreciated and thank you for your time!

https://jsfiddle.net/TonyTheOnly/7ha214r0/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    
        $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){
            
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
        });
});
```

```css
header {
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    
    
}


nav {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    
}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 25px;
    
    position: relative;
    
}

nav a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #000;
    
}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;
    
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    
    .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
   .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
     nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        height:0;
        
    }

    nav ul.open {
        height: auto;
    }
     nav ul li{
        float:none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }


}

@media only screen and (max-width:1050px) {
     
    .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    
   .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
     nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        height:0;
        
    }

    nav ul.open {
        height: auto;
    }
     nav ul li{
        float:none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Responsive menu</title>  
   <div class="container">
    <nav>
       <a class="burger-nav"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve? Its working fine on my localhost, I put it all in one file index.php.

Make sure the way you call your css and js files are correct, also try to force refresh your browser ctrl f5. And this is should be obvious but just to be sure, make sure you are connected to internet. And take note Im using sublime text because its more easy to use for me than brackets.

[image]

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Responsive menu</title>  
   <div class="container">
    <nav>
       <a class="burger-nav"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".burger-nav").on("click", function(){

            $("nav ul").toggleClass("open");
        });
});
</script>


<style type="text/css">

header {
    background: white;
    padding-bottom: 20px;


}


nav {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 10%
}

nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;

}

nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 35px;
    padding-top: 25px;

    position: relative;

}

nav a {
    color: #444;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 24px;
}

nav a:hover {
    color: #000;

}

nav a::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 10px;
    width: 0%;
    background-color: #444;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
}

nav a:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {

    .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

   .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

     nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        height:0;

    }

    nav ul.open {
        height: auto;
    }
     nav ul li{
        float:none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;

    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }


}

@media only screen and (max-width:1050px) {

    .burger-nav{
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    float: right;
    background: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/wirecons-free-vector-icons/32/menu-alt-512.png");
    background-size: cover;
    cursor: pointer;
    }

   .wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0;
    }

     nav ul {
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        height:0;

    }

    nav ul.open {
        height: auto;
    }
     nav ul li{
        float:none;
        text-align: left;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;

    }
    nav ul li a {
        color: black;
        padding: 10px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0;
    }   
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Just by adding the js inline with my html and it worked. So must be a the file calling, but I have other js elements working (a slider) while using the main.js folder. No worries though! it works! Haha thanks again.